# How can I improve performance using a system remotely via SSH?

Tags: ssh, networking, performance

I know I can use compression with the flag `-C`. Any other ideas?

Also, besides my internet connection (which I think is fairly fast), what could be causing the network to slow down?

Comment: If the load average is high, that might cause the connection to be problematic. Easy way to determine that is simply by typing `uptime` on your server.

Comment: Speed doesn't matter. The latency and RTT (Round Trip Time) is important for interactive applications. Compression will just slow down if you have fast connection.

Comment: @Jakuje Based on my tests, that is definitely true.

Answer (score 1):

If you think Network at your end is pretty fast, confirm that with sites like SpeedTest. If you are right, check the System performance you are connecting to, it may be burdened. Also, utilities like ping, traceroute, etc. can help you check the congestion if any as suggested above by @Jakuje. You can also use Wireshark to find more realistic view of what's happening with your packets.

Comment: Traceroute and ping give expected returns. I may have to try SpeedTest and the like. Thanks.

Comment: What are "expected returns"?